# SlideToggle - Delete form data

Tags: jquery

I have an expanding form which expands on click, after clicking additional / advanced options become available, now when expanded I also give the option to go back to the normal / basic form. In this case I want to delete everything that was entered in the advanced part of the form.

I came as far as this:

```
$(function() {
   $('#more').hide();
   $("#advanced_search").click(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show advanced search options' ? 'Hide advanced search options (selected options will be deleted)' : 'Show advanced search options');
         $('#more input').val('');
          $('#swimming-pool').prop('checked', false);
           var select = ("#location"); 
           select.find("option[value='']").attr('selected','selected');
           select.data("selectBox-selectBoxIt").refresh();
    $('#more').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
});
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm using an additional plugin - selectBoxIt, which makes the selects look better. The problem is if I want to reset the select boxes and just do

`$('#location').val('');`

then this sets the value, but does not actually change the visible selected option in the select box. Apparently what you have to do is this:

`select.data("selectBox-selectBoxIt").refresh();`

But as soon as I use that the slideToggle(); goes crazy and stops working (it slides for a split second and goes back up).

The advanced part of the form consists of 3 selects: `#location #ownership #furniture` and some text inputs and a checkbox, they delete just fine, I'm just having trouble with the selects.

fiddle demonstrating the slideToggle issue:  [jsfiddle.net/L3Aux/6](http://jsfiddle.net/L3Aux/6)

Comment: make a fiddle and show us .

Comment: Selectboxit doesn't render properly in a fiddle, basically it does nothing in there and converts the selects to text. But here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/L3Aux/6/  it shows the problem of the toggle going up again without any interaction.

Comment: fix this line with: var select = $("#location");